# How to put <li class="active"> in navigation menu in Yii?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

I am working in Yii and am suddenly stuck in this dilemma. The thing is, till this point I was using CMenu and when working with Bootstrap, I was using TbMenu.

However, in this current project, we have created entirely a different menu with lots of new spans and divs inside, so integrating it with the current TbMenu or Cmenu was proving to be very difficult, so we are putting up the menu HTML as is in the main layout. However, now as I visit any view, it should put the appropriate "active" class in the menu list item.

TbNavbar and CMenu were able to achieve this automatically, however I am not able to implement it for my views.

For example :

I have this in as my navbar :

So when I visit "someController/actionSomthing" like so :

www.localhost.com/someController/actionSomthing

```
<nav>
<ul id="blah">
<li class="active"><a href ="#" >Something</a></li>
<li><a href ="#" >Something else</a></li>
<li><a href ="#" >another something</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

So basically when I visit the specific action/Controller : it should put the class = "active" in the li tag.

Please help.

Regards,

Comment: Your menu code is a secret? $().addClass('active') no?

Comment: Please recheck the question, I have modified it a bit.

Comment: @ineersa is it not possible to do it without jquery?

Comment: Possible if you want to write your own cmenu). You can extend CWidget and do what you want. Look here https://github.com/mrkmg/yii-ext-cssmenu/blob/master/cssmenu/CssMenu.php It's way easier for me to do it with js anyway.

Comment: I have found out a method to do it by editing the core files specifically changing how the view is rendered. However, I am sure that this method is definitely not recommended I am sure?

Comment: Yes editing core files is bad idea. Do it by extending CWidget, like on extension i gave you.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this if you want a JS/jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $('#blah li').each(function() {
        var link = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
        if(loc.indexOf(link) >= 0)
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: True. I use something similar to wrap cssmenu extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this class for `li` items:

```
class="<?php echo (Yii::$app->controller->route == 'site/index') ? 'active' : '' ?>"
```

Also you could use `Yii::$app->controller->id` for direct links.

Answer (score 0):

`TbMenu` is inherit from `CMenu`. In the current project use `active`:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
    'collapse'=>true,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('role'=>'navigation'),
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items'=>array(
                array(
                    'label'=>'Consultas',
                    'url'=>array('/someController/actionSomthing'),
                    'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('someController'),
                    'active'=>Yii::app()->controller->id=='someController'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)) ?>
```